# Как операционная система регулирует нагрузку на процессор?

Tags: ос, планирование

Известно, что операционная система обрабатывает события в бесконечном цикле. Как она подстраивает частоту выполнения тела этого цикла, чтобы процессор не был постоянно загружен на пределе?

Comment: а чем должен быть загружен процессор, если нет задач? А когда задачи есть, то он и загружен.

Comment: Цикл все равно проверяет статус с какой-то частотой.

Comment: ну с какой-то проверяет. Если вы заглядываете в почтовый ящик раз в час в ожидании новых задач, то вряд ли у вас из-за этого загрузка на пределе.

Comment: Ну вот раз в час или раз в наносекунды - как это регулируется?

Comment: В современных процессорах есть команды, которые приостанавливают его до наступления какого-либо события. Вот их и использует планировщик в своем цикле ожидания. Для x86 [посмотрите тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55295884/7286264)

Comment: есть какой-то планировщик, который за этим следит. Больше интересно, как процессор определяет, что сейчас можно бы и частоту повысить, потому что работы навалили :)

Comment: @avp, можно ли в Си такое реализовать?

Comment: @Грузчик, в Си запросто, там есть конструкция [asm](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GCC_Inline_Assembly). Но работать интересующие вас команды будут только в режиме ядра (они т.н. привилигированные)